# How can i get current thread id in function that runs in thread?

Tags: c++

**How can i get current thread ID in a function that runs on the thread?**
I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_TH 4

void printhello(thread t) { 
    auto th_id = t.get_id();
    cout << "Hello world! Thread ID, "<<th_id<< endl;
}

void main() {   
    thread th[NUM_TH];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TH; i++) {
        th[i]=thread(printhello,th[i]); 
        th[i].join();
    }

}
```

i'm getting error "cannot convert argument 1 from void to t"

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is a little ... vague. Does it compile? Does it run without errors? Does it just give the wrong result? Be a little more specific

Comment: When you pass `th[1]` to the `thread` constructor, it hasn't been initialized yet; i.e. it's a blank, invalid `thread` object, not the one that runs `printhello`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Have you read the guide, and in particular "How to ask a good question"? You are getting down-voted and vote-to-close because you haven't told us what the problem actually *is*.  Please [edit] the question so we can help you.  (You should also include all the headers you need in your [mcve])

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `std::this_thread::get_id()`?

Comment: thanks Igor Tandetnik   this_thread::get_id() is what i was looking for :)

Comment: but i can't understand why this question got -4 :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't "work" for so many reasons. First of all make sure it compiles. Second, a thread is not like a simple class like a string. You cannot copy threads; you can only move threads. What you're doing is trying to initialize an "empty" thread to then copy another thread on top of it. What you can do, if you want an array, is to use pointers instead. To get current thread id, you have to use this_thread::get_id();

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#define NUM_TH 4

using namespace std;

void printhello() { 
    auto th_id = this_thread::get_id();
    cout << "Hello world! Thread ID, "<< th_id << endl;
}

int main() {   
    thread* th[NUM_TH];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TH; i++)
    {
        th[i] = new thread(printhello);
        th[i]->join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the thread to the function, you could access the `printhello's` executing thread by `std::this_thread`;

Hence, remove the argument and use `std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();` instead.